# Prestashop- You may also like these products

Tags: prestashop, product

I got one odd things to do on product-detail-page: I want to display some information (image + description 'atleast') for every product. Available options are 'related products' and 'Cross selling' but these are already in use so i need to know something like "YOU MAY ALSO LIKE" products.

Looking for its solution. Any help and suggestion would be great help

Comment: Check out this module - https://www.xtendify.com/en/product/40-Extra_Product_Page_Tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cross selling module when installed displays a list of products also bought by existing customers and displays "customers who bought this product also bought". you could translate by going to localization/ translations/ installed modules translations and selecting your theme then search for "customers who bought this product also bought" and translate to "You may also like these products". It would make sense that new customers would 'also like' what existing customers 'also bought'. hope this helps.

Comment: As i mentioned above cross selling module dont work it becasue :

The crosselling module needs some orders to check if a product was sold together with other products. A list of 'people who bought this product also bought' will only be shown with products that :
1) are already in any old order AND
2) has other products within that same order.
 
Only if those requirements are met, any cross-sold product will be shown.

Comment: Ok I understand, i think this would be difficult unless you were willing to wait for the cross selling module to accumulate data or made phantom orders yourself, a simple way would be to trade the 'accessories' tab for 'may also like'. translate 'Accessories' to 'Products you may also like' and manually add the related products to each product as accessories.

Comment: Ok. I think your idea may work. Can you please also guide me how to manually add products to each product as accessories?

Comment: Sure. Once you have added all of your products and are ready to assign the accessories, go to catalogue/products and select a product you wish to assign to. then choose the associations tab on the left and you will see a field called accessories. Begin to type the product in the field and choose from the dropdown and save. you will then see them appear on a tab in the product page. all you will need to do then is translate the tab name in BO/localization/translations.

Comment: Thanks Gary...will check it

Comment: Glad I could be of help, could you please accept the answer so others can see it solved. Thanks, Gaz.

Comment: @Gary..how to accept answer so that other can see it as solved?